# Firebase cloud functions update document with storage public URL

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

A frontend application is creating documents in firestorm with following model

[image]

> fileRef is string : "gs://bucket-location/folder/fileName.extention"

Now after creation I want to get the public URL of the file and update the document with the URL

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const firebase = admin.initializeApp();

interface DocumentDataType {
  fileRef: string; 
  fileType: "image" | "video";
  fileUrl: string;
  timestamp: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp;
  location: FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint;
}

exports.onDocumentCreated = functions.firestore
  .document("db/{docId}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket();
    const { fileRef } = <DocumentDataType>snapshot.data();
    const file = bucket.file(fileRef);
    const fileUrl = file.publicUrl();
    const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
    batch.update(snapshot.ref, { ...snapshot.data(), fileUrl });
  });
```

The functions get triggered but the file URL does not update.

- is it the right approach for getting the file in cloud storage? -
- and also does SDK v9 update is with batch? I really got confused reading the documentation and could not find a proper solution.

Comment: Where is the document being added from? It might be easier to add image URL doc from client itself while adding the doc at first place.

Comment: @Dharmaraj not really relevant but it seems the frontend app does not have READ permission so cannot get `getDownloadURL()` to append the data

Answer (score 2):

Batched writes are useful when you are trying to add/update/delete multiple documents and want to ensure all the operations either pass or fail. In the provided code you are not commiting the batch. Using `commit()` should update the document:

```
batch.commit().then(() => console.log("Document updated"));
```

However if you just want to update a single document then I would prefer `update()` instead:

```
exports.onDocumentCreated = functions.firestore
  .document("db/{docId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket();
    const { fileRef } = <DocumentDataType>snapshot.data();
    const file = bucket.file(fileRef);
    const fileUrl = file.publicUrl();
    
    return snapshot.ref.update({ ...snapshot.data(), fileUrl });
  });
```